# Update the display on a regular basis in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In flutter, we want to update the display on a regular basis.
We can update the display when the value changes.
However, the set value does not change in this case.
Therefore, we do not know what to do as a trigger to update the display.

We changed from Stateless Widget to Stateful Widget. And we started the timer in initState() and canceled the timer in dispose(). We regularly call notifyListeners () on ScopedModel and are updating the drawing.

It works as expected. Unfortunately, it is not a beautiful way. It is hard to understand, it is annoying. Do not you know a better way? How should we do?

We will clarify our implementation example below. It is a minimal code.

xxxxx_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pregnancy/scoped_model/xxxxx_model.dart';
import 'package:pregnancy/widgets/yyyyy_widget.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class XxxxxWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<XxxxxModel>(
      model: XxxxxModel(),
      child: YyyyyWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

yyyyy_widget.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pregnancy/scoped_model/xxxxx_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class YyyyyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  YyyyyWidgetState createState() {
    return new YyyyyWidgetState();
  }
}

class YyyyyWidgetState extends State<YyyyyWidget> {
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      (Timer t) {
        XxxxxModel.of(context).notify();
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<XxxxxModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) {
        var diff = model.datetime.difference(DateTime.now());
        var hours = diff.inHours.remainder(Duration.hoursPerDay);
        var minutes = diff.inMinutes.remainder(Duration.minutesPerHour);
        var seconds = diff.inSeconds.remainder(Duration.secondsPerMinute);
        return Text('${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

xxxxx_model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class XxxxxModel extends Model {
  static XxxxxModel of(BuildContext context) =>
      ScopedModel.of<XxxxxModel>(context);

  DateTime _datetime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));

  get datetime => _datetime;

  set datetime(DateTime value) {
    _datetime = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void notify() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: What about just `setState({}())` instead of `XxxxxModel.of(context).notify();`?

Comment: `However, the set value does not change in this case.` can you please elaborate little bit?

Comment: I would handle the state on XxxxxWidget meaning I would make this the statefulWidget and leaving as a stateless widget your YyyyyWidgetState class(which will only show the value) When you execute notifyListeners() the statefulwidget will re render and will show you the updated value on the statelesswidget.

Comment: > Günter Zöchbauer 
We added String variable _textDateTime to YyyyyWidgetState class. And we gave it to the Text argument in the builder. We update _textDateTime when a timer occurs. We no longer need to use the notify() method. It became easier to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: > Dinesh Balasubramanian It seems we were a bit confused. If we change the value with SetState the drawing will be updated. But the date and time we set are unchanged. Only the value of DateTime.now () changes. We thought we could not update the drawing. We could solve it by simply creating a String variable.

Comment: > Matias Thank you very much. We will consider that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StreamBuilder` that listens to an interval stream. It automatically manages the subscription.

Your model can provide the stream as a property.

Comment: We were just thinking about learning about it. We will also investigate the difference with ScopedModel.